# constant handle in GetProcAddress(new IntPtr(0xac8), "SomeFoo"), how it`s possible?

Tags: c#, winapi

While reversing a programm faced the code (c#):

```
 IntPtr address = GetProcAddress(new IntPtr(0xac8), "SomeFoo");
```

If I understand right, this handle usually gets from

```
HMODULE WINAPI LoadLibrary(_In_  LPCTSTR lpFileName);
```

or, for example, from

```
HMODULE WINAPI GetModuleHandle(_In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpModuleName);
```

and this handle is dynamic and never points to the same address twice.

The question is: in what case is it possible to use hard coded handle?

UPD: It's no way for this trick to be workable in usual way. So, seems like this call is hooked by kernel driver and this address "0xac8" is just a key for this driver to identify my program call.

Comment: The only reason I may think of is they assumed a fixed address for a system library (such as kernel32, for example). It _was_ true (but terribly fragile) before address space randomization. Now it's just wrong. It may be a proprietary DLL loaded at a preferred address but again it's unportable and extremely fragile (after all base address is just an hint, not a rule). Is it a pretty naive code to _protect_ license related stuff or just result of a hard party night?

Comment: @Adriano That address is in the first page. There's never a module there. Nothing is there.

Comment: It's all for protection for sure) Also, seems like this library loaded with parent process, and this code executes in parent process address space. I'm just trying to understand how it works, and it works for sure.

Comment: @user The term parent process doesn't really make sense. There's really just the process executing the code and then external processes. GetProcAddress accepts module handles that only have meaning in this process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan unless -BASE is used for linker but...well I don't even know if it's possible to _ask_ to put image base in first page.

Comment: @Adriano That first page is reserved by the system

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well so no discussion! It's really a "joke" to obfuscate code (or true value will be injected at run-time?)

Answer (score 2):

> The question is: in what case is it possible to use hard coded handle?

First of all, assuming normal use, there is no situation that I can think of. And certainly no module handle can ever have the value `0xac8` because a module handle is an address. And that address is part of an area that is reserved by the system and is is always invalid to access memory at that address.

So, if that is so then I believe that you have reverse engineered this call incorrectly.

On the other hand, maybe you have reversed engineered correctly. In which case we are not talking about normal usage. So perhaps the process has hooked `LoadLibrary` to perform some special behaviour when passed such a module handle. But at this point we can only speculate.

---

An aside, you also said, "and this handle is dynamic and never points to the same address twice". Well, it is perfectly possible that modules are loaded at the same address repeatedly. Modules have preferred load addresses, and the system tries to reduce the physical memory cost by loading modules at the same address in each process that loads them if possible. However, you cannot assume at compile time what address will be used.

Comment: Well, the onliest thing I'm 100% sure is that i've reverced this call correctly.
idc.i4 2760
newobj System.void System.IntPtr::.ctor(System.Int32)
ldstr SomeFoo
call System.intPtr ....GetProcAddress(System.intptr, System.String)

Comment: "However, you cannot assume at compile time what address will be used." but that's it =) and i wonder how it can be? Is it possible to load library on sprcified addr?

Comment: Ok, "If so then you can replace that call with IntPtr address = IntPtr.Zero;!!!" for what is this? I need to call this foo, not to avoid calling.

Comment: It was a little joke. Your code always returns `IntPtr.Zero`. There is never a module there